# Prevent Session Hijacking in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owasp, session-hijacking

How can we prevent session hijacking in an asp.net mvc application? The following steps were performed by the testers to hijack the session - [OWASP A2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Privilege_escalation_(OTG-AUTHZ-003)).

1. Login as a low-privilege user.
2. Login as a admin user. (in a separate browser - from the same machine)
3. Copied the `ASP.Net Session ID` of the admin user
4. Replaced the `ASP.Net Session ID` of the low-prev user with the that of the admin user.

By doing the above steps, the low-prev user was able to access the admin areas of the app.

1. The application is hosted with `SSL (https)`.
2. Cookies have been set to `Secure` and `HttpOnly`.
3. Cookies are set to expire on `Session_End` and `Signout`.

Still, I am able to reproduce the scenario explained above using `Fiddler`. Could someone please help on ways to arrest the above issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that if someone were able to still the cookie, then she should be able to log in. The mitigation should be using short-lived cookies for sensitive resources, and require the user to re-enter her credentials before doing any sensitive data. For example, setting a password, granting permissions etc. Also, you should make it hard to still a cookie - which seems like you already did. Worth also adding [Same-Site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SameSite)), and keeping your site secure.